# Get checkbox values as array from HTML form in spring

Tags: spring, checkbox

I have a form that displays all the items in my list. There is a checkbox next to each element:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="selected" value="${product.id}">
```

After I click the Continue button, I get into a controller where I want to have a list of all the checkboxes selected. I tried to do it like this:

```
@GetMapping
    public String getOrderForm(Model model, @RequestParam(value = "selected") String[] selected){
```

But I am getting the error that there is no such object. How can I get this checkbox list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in html form need to add this:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="selected" th:value="${product.id}">
```

my controller now looks like this:

```
 @GetMapping
    public String getOrderForm(Model model, @RequestParam(value = "selected", required = false)Integer[] selected){
```

if no checkbox is selected then selected will be null

Answer (score 2):

The controller will accept the checked checkboxes as a comma-separated string.

```
@GetMapping
public String getOrderForm(Model model, @RequestParam("selected") String selected){
    String[] stringArray = selected.split(",");
    List<String> list = Arrays.asList(stringArray);

    ... <your code>

    return "somePage";
}
```

Comment: What should the HTML page look like in this case?

Comment: Please share your html page, i will make changes in the page if required

Answer (score 0):

What chandra kant said is right, but there is one more thing that you need to know to make this work. You have to keep the name of each checkbox same then only it work. It will automatically generate a string separated by comma. You can test it out by printing it in the controller only and you can also see it in the URL.

```
 @GetMapping
 public String getOrderForm(@Param("selected") String selected){
  System.out.println(selected);//just to check whether we are getting comma separated value or not
  String[] selectedArray = selected.split(",");
  List<String> list = Arrays.asList(stringArray);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To receive selected checkbox value as a string array in the controller. You have to specify the value of the name **attribute** of all the checkbox same for the group of the checkbox. And then you will receive the selected checkbox value as an array in the controller.

For the same group of checkbox specific same value for name attribute for a group of checkbox:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="selected" value="${product1.id}">
<input type="checkbox" name="selected" value="${product2.id}">
<input type="checkbox" name="selected" value="${product3.id}">
```

In the controller:

```
@GetMapping
    public String getOrderForm(Model model, @RequestParam(value = "selected") String[] selected){
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
 @GetMapping
 public String getOrderForm(Model model, @RequestParam("selected") String selected){
  System.out.println(selected);//just to check whether we are getting comma separated value or not
  String[] selectedArray = selected.split(",");
  List<String> list = Arrays.asList(stringArray);
}
```